With a valid FRRO certificate, OCI in process and expired PIO, can I travel out of india and return back?
My sister is a US citizen, she has been in India since she was 1 year old ( current age 20) and had never left the country.
She had a PIO card during her entry to the US which was issued until 15 years of her age( as minors only are issued until the age of 15). We have not re-applied for the PIO card at that time, she also had a 1 year gap in the passport as it was COVID.
We have recently obtained a FRRO registration certificate addressing the gap in the passport and have an FRRO physical appointment next week to verify the documents for the OCI.
With the valid US passport, expired PIO, OCO reciept, FRRO registration certificate, will she be able to travel out of india and re-enter without any VISA? We have a trip coming next month and we are not confident we will receive the OCI on time. I am naturally assuming their will be tons of questions at the immigration, but we have all the documentation to prove that she has been in india, proofs of OCI application, we have also paid a fine for the delay in the OCI application( this is also included in the certificate)
Need help!!

She'll be able to leave India with the FRRO certificate but will need a visa or OCI to come back.

@nikhil This is an answer to the OP's question. It should be offered in the "Your Answer" box and not in Comments.
